# Code optimization in selenium webdriver for driver.findElement

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The code which i have written uses find Element method more than 32 times:
i wanted to create a common method for find Element

should i declare any generic method ?

Answer (score 1):

A bit more of info on your code will help answer this. If you are trying to access different elements on your page then you would directly or indirectly end up making these 32 calls.

So first check if you need 32 different elements or not. If not, consider storing the results in variables and reusing them (again depends on your code/flows).

Answer (score 0):

Although it won't make any difference in doing it, but if still you want you can make a method somewhat like this:

```
public WebElement find(String type,String locator){
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 WebElement we;
 if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")){
   we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator));
 }
 if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
   we = driver.findElement(By.id(locator));
 }
 // and so on...
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
WebElement newButton1 = find("id","button1");
WebElement newLink1 = find("xpath","//a[text()='xyz']");
```